# Basic algebra square numbers

Tags: square-numbers

Hello I'm new to algebra, I can't solve this:

$x+\sqrt{x}=13$

$x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=?$

can you help 
Thank you.

Comment: Is the question asking how to find $x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ without computing $\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your equation in the form
$$\sqrt{x}=13-x$$ after squaring we get
$$x^2-27x+169=0$$
can you proceed?

Comment: I guess the question is how to find $x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ *without* finding $x$.

Comment: ... but I guess it can't be done because the answer is $\frac{170-12\sqrt x}{13}$.

Comment: but your term containes the variable $x$?